# How to sum conditionally in pandas

Tags: pandas, sum, conditional-statements

I am trying to populate a DataFrame using the result of a calculation performed on a different DataFrame.
These calculations should be run on a series, when conditions are met in two separate series.

Here is what I have tried.
I have built a dataframe, rswcapacity on which calculations should be run, then created another dataframe annualcapacity where I would like the conditional calculations to be stored.

```
#First DataFrame
d = {'technology': ['EAF', 'EAF', 'EAF', 'BOF', 'BOF', 'BOF'], 'equip_detail1': [150, 130, 100, 200, 200, 150], 'equip_number' : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'capacity_actual': [2400, 2080, 1600, 3200, 3200, 2400], 'start_year': [1992, 1993, 1994, 1989, 1990, 1991], 'closure_year': [ '', 2002, '', '', 2001, 2011] }
rswcapacity = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
rswcapacity['closure_year'].replace('', np.nan, inplace = True)

#Second DataFrame    
annualcapacity = pd.DataFrame(columns=['years', 'capacity'])
annualcapacity ['years'] = [1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]

#Neither of the attempts below yields the desired results:
    for y in years:
        annualcapacity['capacity'].append(rswcapacity['capacity_actual'].apply(lambda x : x['capacity_actual'].sum() (x['start_year'] >= y & (x['closure_year'] <= y | x['closure_year'].isnull()))).sum())
    annualcapacity

#other attempt:
   for y in years:
         if (rswcapacity['start_year'] >= y).any() & ((rswcapacity['closure_year'].isnull()).any() | (rswcapacity['closure_year'] <= y).any()):
            annualcapacity['capacity'].append(rswcapacity['capacity_actual'].sum())
    annualcapacity
```

The result I would like to obtain is a sum performed for every year.
For instance:
1985 should return NaN as 1985 is smaller than any of the years in start_year 1992 should return 14880, as 1992 is larger than any start_year and smaller than any closure_year
2001 should return 7200, as it is larger than all start_year and larger of all closure_years.
Instead all three my attempts are only returning NaN across the list of years.

There is something wrong with my setting the conditions, but have not managed to work out what.

Any insight much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
# start with an empty dataframe for the summed capacity
# with int32 as type of the year and float32 as type for the capacity
annualcapacity = pd.DataFrame({'years': pd.Series(dtype='int32'), 'capacity': pd.Series(dtype='float32')})

# use your list of years
years=  [1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]

for y in years:
    # create a sum for each year
    indexer= (rswcapacity['start_year'] <= y) & ((rswcapacity['closure_year'].isnull()) | (rswcapacity['closure_year'] >= y))
    capa= rswcapacity.loc[indexer, 'capacity_actual'].sum()
    # and append it to the result frame
    annualcapacity= annualcapacity.append(dict(years=y, capacity=capa), ignore_index=True)

annualcapacity
```

The result looks like this:

```
    years  capacity
0    1980       0.0
1    1981       0.0
2    1982       0.0
3    1983       0.0
4    1984       0.0
5    1985       0.0
6    1986       0.0
7    1987       0.0
8    1988       0.0
9    1989    3200.0
10   1990    6400.0
11   1991    8800.0
12   1992   11200.0
13   1993   13280.0
14   1994   14880.0
15   1995   14880.0
16   1996   14880.0
17   1997   14880.0
18   1998   14880.0
19   1999   14880.0
20   2000   14880.0
21   2001   14880.0
22   2002   11680.0
23   2003    9600.0
24   2004    9600.0
25   2005    9600.0
26   2006    9600.0
27   2007    9600.0
28   2008    9600.0
29   2009    9600.0
30   2010    9600.0
31   2011    9600.0
32   2012    7200.0
33   2013    7200.0
34   2014    7200.0
35   2015    7200.0
36   2016    7200.0
37   2017    7200.0
38   2018    7200.0
39   2019    7200.0
40   2020    7200.0
```

**Note:** the sums are always numeric, so if there is no capacity for a year, the value is 0.0 instead of `NaN`. If you need `NaN` for some reason, you can replace it with the line below.
The second point is, that I switched your condition,

```
(rswcapacity['start_year'] >= y) & ((rswcapacity['closure_year'].isnull()) | (rswcapacity['closure_year'] <= y))
```

so `>=` became `<=` because I thought, you want to sum all capacities which were available for that year, right?

So if you need `NaN` entries instead of 0.0 if no capacity is available at all, you can do that as follows:

```
annualcapacity.loc[annualcapacity['capacity] == 0, 'capacity']= np.NaN
```

For this, you need to add `import numpy as np` in your header.

Comment: For utmost clarity, it could be worth incorporating the switching of conditions in your code

Comment: Hi @Valentina, what do you mean by "the switching of conditions"? oh I just recognized that I copied the old version of the condition in my code, do you mean that? I'll change it, thank you.

Comment: Hello! that was it! It made me think more deeply about the conditions :-)